# R: Import data from multiple file paths and store in a list

Tags: r, list, import

I have some data which I would like to read in from seperate .txt files based on individual paths. A sample folder structure with txt files can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5owbj8vnp18cp2/Data.zip?dl=0).

The (sample) data.frame I have looks like this

```
data <-   structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Test1", "Test10", "Test2", "Test6"), class = "factor"), Metadata = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("asdajl7", "asfhas", "sgash", "uashas8"), class = "factor"), Filepath = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Folder1/File8.txt", "Folder7/file2.txt", "Folder9/File19.txt"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", "Metadata", "Filepath"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

data
    Name Metadata           Filepath
1  Test1    sgash  Folder1/File8.txt
2  Test2  uashas8  Folder7/file2.txt
3  Test6  asdajl7 Folder9/File19.txt
4 Test10   asfhas
```

In order to make a reproducible example I tried to implement the following function to adjust the filepath to the place where you saved the Folder structure from the Download above.

```
# Choose path to unzipped Data directory
choose.dir <- function() {
  system("osascript -e 'tell app \"R\" to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt \"Choose Data Folder:\")' > /tmp/R_folder",
         intern = FALSE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
  p <- system("cat /tmp/R_folder && rm -f /tmp/R_folder", intern = TRUE)
  return(ifelse(length(p), p, NA))
}
a <- choose.dir()
if(is.na(a)) stop("No folder", call. = F)
# paste ready to use path together
data$completepath <- paste0(a,"/",data$Filepath)
data$completepath <- gsub("//", "/", data$completepath)
```

The data.frame now looks like this (I unzipped the folder structure to my Desktop):

```
data
    Name Metadata           Filepath                               completepath
1  Test1    sgash  Folder1/File8.txt  /Users/XYZ/Desktop/Data/Folder1/File8.txt
2  Test2  uashas8  Folder7/file2.txt  /Users/XYZ/Desktop/Data/Folder7/file2.txt
3  Test6  asdajl7 Folder9/File19.txt /Users/XYZ/Desktop/Data/Folder9/File19.txt
4 Test10   asfhas                                      /Users/XYZ/Desktop/Data/
```

How could I read in the data from the different .txt files using a loop so that I get the following list structure?

```
   List with 3 elements
        1.1 (5 observations and 5 Variables)
        $Name chr[1:5] Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1
        $Year num[1:5] 1783 1784 1785 1786 1787
        $data1 num[1:5] 12 53 13.1 12.9 16
        $data2 num[1:5] 56 5 532 27 9
        $data3 num[1:5] 0.1 9 42 2 13
        1.2 (4 observations and 3 variables)
        $Name chr[1:4] Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2
        $Year num[1:4] 1387 1388 1389 1390
        $data num[1:4] 78.9 27 12.3 0.9
        1.3 (3 observations and 3 variables)
        $Name chr[1:3] Test6 Test6 Test6
        $Test1 chr[1:3] hajshf asfhah ashsa
        $Year num[1:3] 2001 2002 2003
```

What I tried is the following, but this doesn't work as the empty filepath of Test10 is causing problems. Can someone help me?

```
# read in the data
f <- file.path(data$completepath)
d <- lapply(f, read.table)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do it this way, you could write the path out instead

```
setwd("/home/christie/Downloads/Data/")
```

This will give all of the paths to every file in the working directory

```
files<-list.files(getwd(),recursive=TRUE)
```

This reads them all into the list

```
d<-lapply(files,function(x) read.table(x, header=T))

str(d)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ data1: num [1:5] 12 53 13.1 12.9 16
  ..$ data2: int [1:5] 56 5 532 27 9
  ..$ data3: num [1:5] 0.1 9 42 2 13
  ..$ year : int [1:5] 1783 1784 1785 1786 1787
 $ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ data: num [1:4] 78.9 27 12.3 0.9
  ..$ year: int [1:4] 1387 1388 1389 1390
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ data1: int [1:3] 18 39 371
  ..$ Test1: Factor w/ 3 levels "asfhah","ashsa",..: 3 1 2
  ..$ Year : int [1:3] 2001 2002 2003
```

Comment: this works partially, thank you! but with this approach all the data in the 'Data' folder is read in. For example if I have some additional files and folders I don't want to have imported I am running into problems as this approach imports everything...

Comment: You'd need to manually remove the paths from files that you do not wish to read, or if there is something shared amoung all file names or folder names that are not to be read you can write a script to remove them from files. You could also just move the folders and/or files out of ../Data/ that you didn't want.